# Being new to react native, implementing api integration but returning html

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am integrating api in react native but the response comes in html while it runs fine on postman. Here is my code

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('userNameOrEmailAddress', 'abc@123.pqr');
  params.append('password', '123456');
console.log("params", params);

axios.post(
  apiUrl, 
  params,
  {
    headers: { 
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
  }).then(response => {
  console.log("response", response.data);
  const { targetUrl } = response.data;
  console.log("target", targetUrl);
  props = targetUrl;
  console.log("props", props);

  
  Alert.alert(
    "App",
    "User success",
    [
      {
        text: "Ok",
        onPress: () => 
        navigation.navigate('MainView' , {
          url: targetUrl
        })
      },
    ],
    {
      cancelable: true,
      onDismiss: () =>
        Alert.alert(
          "This alert was dismissed by tapping outside of the alert dialog."
        ),
    }
  )
}).catch(error => {
  console.log("error", error);
  // const errors = {};

  // this.setState({ 
  //   errors: errors,
  // });
});
```

};

I have tried many methods but changes here don't work as desired, The api works fine sometimes but at other times, it returns html. Any help in this case will be really relieving.

Comment: 'The api works fine sometime but at other times, it returns html' ? - Firstly, 'ensure' your api is working fine all the time, otherwise you might be  asking the wrong question

Comment: its not working, always returning html response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this was expo app cache. Actually when I run this on a different device with new expo installed, it worked. That sounds strange, but it happened. Now every time I run into this issue, I uninstall expo and reinstall, it works. Don't know the exact issue but this solution, might be a temporary one, is working for me.

Update:

Resolved this issue by using anti-forgery token. There is an extra security required on this so got the token and passed in every api to resolve the same.

Comment: may be you can check this. You can reset cache rather than installing and uninstalling. https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-clear-the-expo-and-react-native-packager-caches-metro-watchman-haste/1352/9

Comment: Reset cache doesn't help. It happens with andriod only. iOS running smoothly.